# total number of unique permutaions

Tags: c++, backtracking

Given a collection of numbers that might contain duplicates, return all possible unique permutations.

https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations-ii/

I am failing on very large test case can someone help me where i am doing wrong.
I am doing  `(i==j||nums[i]!=nums[j])` to avoid duplicates rest is simple backtracking.

```
class Solution {
public:
    void solve(vector<vector<int>>&res,int j,vector<int>&nums){
        if(j==nums.size()){
            res.push_back(nums);
            return;
        }
        for(int i=j;i<nums.size();i++){
            if(i==j||nums[i]!=nums[j]){
            swap(nums[i],nums[j]);
            solve(res,j+1,nums);
            swap(nums[i],nums[j]);}
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int>> permuteUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>>res;
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        solve(res,0,nums);
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't have to manually generate the permutations. There is `std::next_permutation.`

Comment: This is a interview problem interviewer will not allow to use that

Comment: Whereas you don't permute duplicate directly, you allow to swap duplicated pairs with duplicated pairs: `A1 A2 B1 B2` : A1 <-> B1 and A2 <-> B2 versus A1 <-> B2 and A2 <-> B1

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Function to find all Permutations of a given string str[i..n-1]
// containing all distinct characters
void permutations(string str, int i, int n)
{
// base condition
if (i == n - 1)
{
    cout << str << endl;
    return;
}

// process each character of the remaining string
for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
{
    // swap character at index i with current character
    swap(str[i], str[j]);       // STL swap() used

    // recur for string [i+1, n-1]
    permutations(str, i + 1, n);

    // backtrack (restore the string to its original state)
    swap(str[i], str[j]);
  }
  }

// Find all Permutations of a string
int main()
{
string str = "ABC";

permutations(str, 0, str.length());

return 0;
}
```